# "in the street outside vs in the street"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What's the difference between **"in the street outside"** & **"in the street"**? Is there a difference in meaning?

Are they the same in their meaning:

> I could see a dark shape **in the street outside**.
>
> I could see a dark shape **in the street**.
>
> I could see a dark shape **outside**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two examples in your question ("I could see a dark shape in the street [outside]") sound pretty much the same to me as a British English speaker, and both sound natural. The only real difference is that one clearly implies that the narrator is "inside" without needing additional context:

> I could see a dark shape in the street

The narrator's location is unspecified.

> I could see a dark shape in the street outside.

The narrator is not outside: they are likely inside a building, vehicle, or similar.

In practice the sentences are more or less identical, and are both perfectly idiomatic.

---

The third case is a little different:

> I could see a dark shape outside.

The shape may not be in the street (which probably implies being on the road or pedestrian pavement), but -- as in a horror movie -- clinging to one's window, building, or in the sky. The narrator is still implied to not be outside.